# Auto generate class diagram cli tool for CI

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, class-diagram, auto-generate

We just finished a webservice and I just created a SHFB project file to generate chm and html documentation (with auto inserted example code snippets!) being build on a TeamCity server. The last thing I need, is a tool to auto generate a class diagram (with associations!) based on a namespace, class names or similar (C#). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) supports [generating class diagrams](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) (at least for C++), try it out.

Comment: Ideally I wanted a standalone tool to generate a jpeg or similar, to include reference in my sandcastle project. So doxigen is not exactly what I'm looking for, but I'll check it out.